# split single variable value in two

Tags: sas

i have dataset a

```
data q7;
input trt$;
cards;
a150
b250
c300
400
abc180
;
run;
```

We have to create dataset b like this

```
trt    dose
a150   150mg
b250   250mg
c300   300mg
400    400mg
abc180 180mg
```

new dose variable is added & mg is written after each 
numeric values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is my solution - Basically use the `compress` functions to keep (hence the `'k'`) only numbers from the `trt` variable. From there then is just the case of concatenating ***mg*** to numbers.

```
data want;
set q7;
dose = cats(compress(trt,'0123456789','k'),'mg');
run;
```

The `compress` function default behaviour is to return a character string with specified characters removed from the original string.

so

`compress(trt,'0123456789')` would have removed all numbers from the `trt` variable.

However `compress` comes with a battery of modifiers that let the user alter the default behaviour.
So in your case, we wanted to keep numbers regardless of the number of preceding letters so I used the modifier `k` to keep instead the list of characters in this case `012345679`

For a full list of modifiers please read the following [link](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000212246.htm)

`cats` is one of the many functions SAS have to concatenate strings, so passing the compress argument as 1st string and ***mg*** as 2nd string will concatenate both to produce your desired result

hope it helps

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩 - fair enough, added a ***why*** this works.

Comment: can you please elaborate               cats(compress(trt,'0123456789','k'),'mg'); statement

Comment: @bhavnish added a bit of explanation on the `compress` function